# How Can I solve This Error 'encore' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: webpack-5, webpack-encore, symfony6

I installed 'Encore Webpack' in my Symfony project. When I try to run `npm run build` I get the error `'encore' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file` How do I resolve this error. PS I am developing on a Windows OS

Comment: Did you do an `npm install`?

Comment: `npm install` resolved the error. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should run `npm install` first